# parse error handleDismissClick = e =>

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

> SyntaxError: /Users/mumuhou/github/web/react/examples/basic-commonjs/index.js: Unexpected token (7:21) while parsing file: /Users/mumuhou/github/web/react/examples/basic-commonjs/index.js

**My code:**

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class App extends Component {
  handleDismissClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  render() {
    var elapsed = Math.round(this.props.elapsed  / 100);
    var seconds = elapsed / 10 + (elapsed % 10 ? '' : '.0' );
    var message =
      'React has been successfully running for ' + seconds + ' seconds.';

    return <p>{message}</p>;
  }
}

var start = new Date().getTime();

setInterval(function() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App elapsed={new Date().getTime() - start} />,
    document.getElementById('container')
  );
}, 200);
```

I have config es2015

Comment: You are missing the the class properties plugin: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

Comment: Also please read [ask] a proper question.

Comment: Duplicate of [React syntax error when adding class properties](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35006643/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class App extends Component {
  handleDismissClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
}
```

is the [*public class fields*](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/) proposal. In order for Babel to understand and convert it, you have to load the [corresponding plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/), or simply use the [*stage-2* preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/).